# NVIDIA 260 GTX: what adapter do i use to get an hdmi port?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi

[image: Nvidia 260GTX]

What adapter do I use for the first port from the left to get HDMI out? I didn't get one with my Dell 8100 XPS computer.

**UPDATE**
I don't think it's an S-video output according to this spec sheet: http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gtx_260_us.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [DVI to HDMI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HDJY7K) cord has worked for me (That one seems to be under 3 USD at times).

Answer (score 2):

Its S-Video, DVI and DVI - you generally can trivially convert DVI to HDMI. I don't think S-Video to HDMI converters are common, and s-video is generally lower resolution anyway, and analogue, so such a converter, should it exist, might be expensive

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy a DVI to HDMI like other people have said. But there is one other connection that needs to be made in order to get the full use out of the HDMI connection. On the side of the card (non PCIe edge). There is a small port that has a rubber cap on it. Under the cap is a connection that has 2 pins. This connector gets hooked to your internal SPDIF header (look in your motherboard manual). This connector is for passing audio to the video card so it can be sent out through the HDMI / DVI adapter connector.

If you still have all of the stuff that came with that card you should have a cable. If not you should be able to find one on ebay or something. If you don't care about sound being sent over the HDMI / DVI then you can just skip that.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is an S-video out. You can use something like:

[This](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/400309329713?lpid=82)

[Or this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003NS0UUQ)